# Solving a functional equation symbolically

Tags: equation-solving, function-construction, algebraic-manipulation

How would i go about manipulating the following:

```
f(f(f(x))) = f(f(x)) + x
```

To find `f(x)` symbolically?

For instance, how would i go about finding `f(0)` given that equation?

Comment: `f[x_]:=a x` with `a` the solution of `a^3 == a^2 + 1` gives three solutions.  There may well be others.

Comment: Do you want to know how to program the software *Mathematica* to solve this problem, which is what this site is about?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, i would like to know how to program mathematica to solve this composite equation.

Comment: OK. It was unclear, because the problem is not posed with proper *Mathematica* syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We re-cast the equation as a recurrence relation. Taking
\begin{align*}
x_n&=x,\\
x_{n+1}&=f(x_n),\\
x_{n+2}&=f(f(x_n)),\\
x_{n+3}&=f(f(f(x_n))),
\end{align*}
this becomes the relation
$$x_{n+3}=x_{n+2}+x_n.$$

We now use *Mathematica*'s `RSolve`:

```
RSolve[x[n + 3] == x[n + 2] + x[n], x[n], n]
(* {{x[n] -> 
      C[1] Root[-1 - #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1]^n + 
      C[2] Root[-1 - #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2]^n + 
      C[3] Root[-1 - #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3]^n}} *)
```

Evidently, there are three linearly independent solutions. These functions are just multiplication by the roots of the polynomial `-1 - x^2 + x^3`, e.g.

```
f[x_, n_ /; 1 <= n <= 3] := x Root[-1 - #1^2 + #1^3 &, n]
```

This shows that [bbgodfrey](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1063/bbgodfrey)'s guess of a solution in their comment was all of the solutions.